# How it works? FINDSTR /M "string\>"

Tags: regex, batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to search a string in the format of REQ_XXXX.

XXXX may be 4 or 5 digit number.
5 digit number may contain 4 digit number. i.e 10029 contains 1002

How to search exactly? Suppose if i am searching for REQ_1002 in three .adb file, it should return the exact file name. It should not return the file name of 10029.
To solve the above problem
I tried:

```
FINDSTR /M "\<REQ_1002\>" *.adb
```

It is working properly for REQ_1002.But this is not finding the file name for REQ_1300. Explain the reason?

Comment: i tried with FINDSTR /M "string" *.adb >>Output.txt

Comment: i also tried with FINDSTR /M "string\>" *.adb >>Output.txt

Comment: if i searched for REQ_1002 file name, first one giving file name of both i.e 1002 and 10029.

Comment: If i searched for REQ_1002 file name, later giving file name of 1002alone but it is not working for others...for example If i searched for REQ_2130, it wont return the file name...HOW TO BOTH PROBLEM?

Comment: `FINDSTR` allows an limited and non-standard [regular expressions use](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html); this might be helpful though. Please, don't add comments to your own question. [Update it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27330524/edit) rather.

Comment: What should I explain? IMHO _your_ question is completely unclear as for your goals: e.g. suppose we have three `.adb` files: first exclusively containing `REQ_1002.XXXX`, second `REQ_10029.XXXX`, third `REQ_51002.XXXX`, then `FINDSTR /M "1002" *.adb` returns all 3 filenames. If wanted another result, please specify your goal [by updating your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27330524/edit) exactly, as this example allows more solvings (1,2,3,12,13,23,123). Specify _rules_ for desired match. Also tag your question `regex` instead of `batch-rename`

Comment: Sorry...Now my question is clear?

Comment: If you are searching for substring in file _name_, try this approach: `dir /B *.adb | findstr /I /M /R "^REQ_1002.adb$"`. Here `/R`= _use string as a regular expression_, `.`= _wildcard: any character_ and, for line position: `^`= _beginning of line_ , `$`= _end of line_.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to search in all *.adb files for a string starting with **REQ_** and exactly with 4 digits and get returned just the name of the files containing such a string. Files containing **REQ_** with 5 digits should be ignored.

The command [findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) can be used for this task even with its limited regular expression capabilities.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /R "\<REQ_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>" *.adb
```

might be what you need to get the names of the *.adb files containing just **REQ_1002** or just **REQ_1300**, but not just **REQ_10029**.